# Set of continuous functions in a bounded subset of all integrable functions is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $M$ be a bounded subset of $C_{[a, b]}$. Prove that the set of all functions

$$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$$

with $f \in M$ is compact.

I have the following results which might be helpful

Every countable compact metric space is totally bounded.

A metric space is compact if and only if it is totally bounded and complete.

I thought about showing that $M$ is totally bounded but couldn't do it.

Comment: What did the problem _really_ ask???

Comment: I copied it. I suppose it asks to prove that the set of all functions which are given by the integral form is compact where $f$ is in $M$.

Comment: I can see what the problem above asks. The problem as above is nonsense, because there's no hypothesis regarding $M$.

Comment: I am sorry. Did not realize this. M is assumed to be a bounded subset. I did mention it in the title but forgot to add it to the actual problem statement. I edited it now.

Comment: No, you didn't even mention this in the title! The title is simply wrong, btw: It's not true that a bounded subset is compact, and that's not what the question asks. You're given that $M$ is bounded, but $M$ is not the set you're trying to show is compact...

Comment: Hint: The Arzela-Ascoli theorem says exactly what the compact subsets of $C([a,b])$ are.

Comment: Also the given set is _not_ compact. Were you really asked to show it's compact, or maybe just precompact?

Comment: Kolmogorov and Fomin Introductory Real Analysis on p. 107 Problem 3: Let $M$ be a bounded subset of the space $C_{[a, b]}$. Prove that the set of all functions $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$ with $f \in M$ compact.

Comment: And I assumed that " ... with $f \in M$ compact" is a mistake and should be "... with $f \in M$ $\textbf{is}$ compact"

Answer (score 0):

This is not so.

Just to give it a name, let $S$ be the set of all $F$ such that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ for some $f\in M$. Assuming $M$ bounded does not imply $S$ is compact;  it does imply that $S$ is precompact.

Say $[a,b]=[-1,1]$. Let $M$ be the set of all continuous $f$ with $|f(t)|\le1$ for all $t$. Let $$f_n(t)=\begin{cases}0,&(t\le0), \\nt,&(0\le t\le 1/n), \\1,&(t>1/n),\end{cases}$$and define $F_n(x)=\int_{-1}^x f_n$. Then $F_n\to  F$ uniformly, where $$F(t)=\begin{cases}0,&(t\le 0),\\t,&(t>0).\end{cases}$$Then $F_n\in S$, $F_n\to F$ uniformly but $F\notin S$; hence the sequence $(F_n)$ cannot have a subsequence converging uniformly to ann element of $S$.

Comment: So as I understand it the question should be phrased: "Is the set $S$ compact?". And then say no it is only pre-compact because of your answer?